# How to enable notification area (systray) for Pidgin

Tags: 11.04, unity-2d, notification

The Pidgin icon won't appear in the notification area. I have already checked if the "Show system tray icon option" is set to "Always" in the Pidgin Preferences.
I didn't find an equivalent solution as those in the case of Unity.

Answer (score 10):

You have to whitelist the applications if you want to allow them to access the system tray.

Firstly install dconf-tools from the software center ( or by [clicking here](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/dconf-tools))
Then Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `dconf-editor` and run it.

[image: dconf-editor alt-f2 dialog]

Now navigate to Desktop -> Unity -> Panel.

[image: configuration editor (dconf-editor) desktop.unity.panel]

Now change the value of  systray-whitelist to

```
['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'scp-dbus-service', 'Pidgin']
```

[image]

Comment: Also to take effect you need to restart Unity: unity --replace

Comment: Didn't work with 'pidgin', but worked with **'Pidgin'** instead.

Comment: doesn't work for me for some reason. i tried Pidgin and pidgin and nothing happened. any suggestions?

Comment: It works with the messaging menu.

Comment: At the beginning it looked like the icon didn't show up, but then I spotted it in a strange place - atop of the 'Desktop' sign in the top left corner of the first of my two monitors. Launching skype moved the icon to the second monitor. A little odd but somehow works...

Comment: dconf-editor doesn't show those option in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 8):

Pidgin won't show up in the systray, just in the messaging menu:
[image]

Now for any other application to show up in the systray run the following code in the terminal: 
`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"`

Comment: I use Unity 2D instead of Unity (I've specified this in the title of my question but apparently it  was too long to be seen). Can you help with a solution for this case?

Comment: Well , I tried unity 2d with pidgin , and it seems like pidgin doesn't support systray in Ubuntu 11.04 , it shows on the messaging menu.Click on the messaging menu and you will see pidgin.