# Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome classic trayicon doesn't work (at least for Pidgin)

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic, system-tray, messaging-tray

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome classic.
Pidgin's tray icon doesn't show up. The settings is ok ("Always").

For any case, I've also added it in dconf-editor as per [How to enable notification area (systray) for Pidgin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41632/how-to-enable-notification-area-systray-for-pidgin) although that's probably only for unity.

Also I've reinstalled and restarted Pidgin.
But still no success - no trayicon anywhere.

I wanted to check whether I have the taskbar in the UI, but I have no idea how to set up panels in Gnome classic. Right-click on panel doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: See here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/136733/some-system-tray-icons-invisible-in-gnome-classic-12-04/146682#146682

It worked for me.

Comment: OMG, Alt + Win + Right click to manage panel? #UsabilityFail

Comment: @volant, if you form it as an answer with the 2 steps, I'll accept.

Comment: BTW I filed a [bug/RFE](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/konsole/+bug/1071041) to add Notification Area by default.